# How to bring up the ppp0 interface?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I am trying to start my pptpd server on Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and I was following the instructions at [this page](https://sskaje.me/2013/10/notes-pptpl2tp-server-on-ubuntu/) and [Ubuntu's official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer). I am doing this because I wanted to setup a VPN server and access that VPN using my cellphone. (My laptop and my cellphone share the same wifi). Initially, when I followed the instructions @ the Ubuntu's guide and I did a `ifconfig`, I got an interface called ppp0 and my cellphone was able to connect to the VPN. I then suspended my laptop for some time  (sleep mode) and then tried to check again but now I am not able to see the ppp0 interface and, I guess, that's the reason I'm also not being able to connect to the VPN using my cellphone.

I tried to restart the pptpd service using `sudo /etc/init.d/pptpd restart` but it doesn't bring up the interface. I am sure the service starts after giving the "restart" command because the command `sudo netstat -anp | grep pptpd` gives me the following output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3928/pptpd      
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    25837    3928/pptpd
```

I am not sure what went wrong and do I need to get back the interface and get my VPN running. Can anyone please help?